# How to best represent movie actors as a binary vector using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, similarity

I have a database of movies. Each movie has an Actors field among other fields represented as an Array of Strings like:

```
['Johny Depp', 'Leonardo DiCaprio', 'John Malkovich']
```

I've already done Plot-based similarity calculation using Spark's ml TF/IDF along with the cosine similarity. 
But case with actors seems different as I wouldn't want to weight different actors differently. I'm just looking for a representation of actor's occurrence in a movie.

So, I was thinking to use something like binary `SparseVector` of length N (total number of actors in corpus) where 1 means that an actor is present in a movie and 0 otherwise. This way I could also calculate cosine similarity between those vectors.

So, having a DataFrame of movies with an Actors column (`Array[String]`), is there an efficient way to get such representation? Maybe mllib has something that I haven't noticed? Still new to Spark.

Comment: How come is it a duplicate? It's not even connected

Comment: Alright, now I see. Cheers